# What does "five" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, donnie-brasco

At a restaurant, Sonny asks a man, who played a poker game:

> Sonny Black: Fucking booths. $200 in action and what we have we got,
> **five**?
>
> Man: We're taking a beating again this week, Sonny.

What does "five" mean?

Comment: YouTube link would be handy - also whether he actually says "two hundred dollars" or just "two hundred".

Comment: Checked on a local copy, timestamp 38:53. Audio says, "Fucking Boots. Two hundred in action & whadda we got? Five?" Subs say "booths" &  "$200". Subs guessed at, long after the fact, I'd go with ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### $5,000 (or perhaps $5 but probably not)

From the script I could find it was (originally?) worded differently which makes it even more clear

```
THE FLUSH OF A TOILET
as Sonny emerges from the bathroom, reading a slip of paper.
Crumples it, throws it in the trash.

         SONNY
      (complaining)
Two hundred in action and we came
out with 35. That fucking Boots-
he runs that book like an old
lady. That's gonna change.
```

Later in the script they're talking about money owned in the order of hundreds of thousands.  So "$200 in action" and "five" probably means $200,000 and $5,000 rather than $200 and $5.

Comment: There's a later version of the script, a bit closer to the final line - "That fucking Boots -- two hundred in action and we come out with a dime?" There's a later line "He went crossda street to get the action from Boots" which suggests he's a character we never actually see. [For the Brits, I think it's extremely doubtful he went to the chemist's ;))

Comment: Yeah @Tetsujin - looking back at my script they are playing 'gin' not poker.  This is just a game for fun.  The 'dime' line suggests that even more.

Comment: Ahh, reading through the whole scene, Sonny's dialog refers to his trip to Boots',  not to anything going on in the gin game - so it could easily be thousands, not chump change. The later script loses the bathroom & has Sonny coming in from the front door. https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/scripts/donnie-brasco-1997.pdf pages 47-49

Comment: Yeah, it might be nice if the OP posts more than this so we can be sure about the actual movie.

Comment: So I edited it again to go back to the original $5,000

Comment: Yeah, it's so long since I saw it, a video link would be useful - I'm not sure, based on the context in the script scenes that we're really going to get a definitive answer as to what dollar value "5" has.